# Ignoring small areas in QGIS join attributes by location

Tags: qgis, intersection, attribute-joins

I want to add the attributes of a first data layer, of selected land ownership data, to a second layer, of land parcels across the county. The second layer covers the whole of the county, the first only parts of it.

The difficulty I have is that the first layer's boundaries do not align to the second, so there are very small areas of overlap for some parcels that should not really be there. So if I use intersect as the geometric predicate in 'join attributes by location', the attributes of the first layer gets added to the joined layer for those very small areas of overlap, even though they do not in reality apply. I have tried using the largest overlap join type, but this does not work either.

All I can think to do is to run an intersection  with the first layer as the input layer and the second as the overlay layer, and then to delete the smallest parcels created in the resultant layer and run join attribute by location using 'intersect' or perhaps 'contains' as the geometric predicate, although this may lose me some data.

Will this work and is it the best route?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: You could perhaps get the centroids of the parcels and use those for the intersection

Comment: You could apply a negative buffer to the first layer to eliminate unwanted overlaps. You write: "largest overlap join type, but this does not work either." - can you explain why?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Centroids wont work as the polygons in the 1st layer cover more than one polygon in the 2nd layer. The negative buffer may work though, on a trial and error basis for the size of the buffer. This seems a better option than 'snap to grid'. The way 'largest overlap' join type works is not explained in the QGIS literature. But my assumption is that it only applies if two or more features from the input layer overlap with the output layer and then it chooses the largest overlap. If there is only one overlapping feature then QGIS takes the attributes from that one.